# PHP - Refactoring / improving Ifs

Tags: php, refactoring

I have the following data structure;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([suit] => c [rank] => A ) 
        [1] => Array ( [suit] => d [rank] => A ) )
```

I want to test if these cards are certain values and display an appropriate message;

```
if (
    (($hand[0]['rank'] == "A") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "A")) 
 || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "K") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "K"))
 || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "Q") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "Q"))  
 || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "A") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "K"))
 || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "K") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "A"))    
   ) {
    echo "Action: Raise pre-flop. Re-raise if already raised.<br />\n";
}

 if (
       (($hand[0]['rank'] == "7") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "7"))
    || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "A") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "J") && ($hand[0]['suit'] == $hand[1]['suit']))
    || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "J") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "Q") && ($hand[0]['suit'] == $hand[1]['suit']))
    || (($hand[0]['rank'] == "10") && ($hand[1]['rank'] == "J") && ($hand[0]['suit'] == $hand[1]['suit']))
       ) {
        echo "Action: Worth a call pre-flop (provided no-one has raised).<br />\n";
    }
```

I have simplified the IFs by removing some of the conditions.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to use in_array() method

[php.net in_array()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use references like this:

```
$rank0 =& $hand[0]['rank'];
$rank1 =& $hand[1]['rank'];

if (
($rank0 == "A" && $rank1 == "A")
|| (...)
```

Just, as the first step to code minimization

Comment: Thanks. I have come up with a solution which is a combination of both of the replies. Perfect. Many thanks.